# Jquery select/unselect works on simple html but not with php loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

When I click on select all, I get all the checkboxes checked and disabled, and when I uncheck select all, all checkboxes become unchecked and normal again.

Then I tried to do the exact same thing with retrieving data from the db with a loop and I can select all, but when I deselect 'select all' it will all get unchecked but disabled.. how can I "undisable" it?

Demo for simple html version: http://jsfiddle.net/k6R7g/11/

The php version that doesn't work:

```
<?php 
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" class="category_all" value="0">All';
if ( $db_conn = connDB() ){
    $sql_categories = "SELECT * FROM cat";
    $rs = getRows($sql_categories, $db_conn);

    foreach ($rs as $row) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="categories_list" name="category[]" value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'';
    }
    $db_conn = null;
}                                       
?>
```

The rows echo fine in the dropdown, just the deselection part of 'select all' isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Chrome and FF work fine for me, IE 11 blocks jQuery library and so does not work.

Comment: im using chrome. Either way I have to make sure it works on everything

Comment: What version of chrome? OS? Chrome 37 on widows works fine. Can you post the html rendered by your browser.

Comment: im not sure what chrome, but it should work on anything so since I don't have it working then something is wrong. And the render is exactly like jsfiddle just in a loop instead of hardcode

Comment: I understand. Usually the first step towards resolving a problem is being able to replicate it. While looking for ways to do that, we cannot rule out any possibilities. I guess I would say I have hit a wall ... ... I can't think of anything else for a cause. ... How does [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/k6R7g/12/) look?

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

```
$(".categories_list").prop("checked", is_checked).attr("disabled",  is_checked);
```

To:

```
$(".categories_list").prop("checked", is_checked).prop("disabled",  is_checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, noraml jquery it is working fine. Hopefully this will work in php. Update your jquery block like below.

```
$(function() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("category_all")) { 
        var is_checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if(is_checked){
        $(".categories_list").prop("checked", is_checked).attr("disabled","true");
        }
        else
        {
         $(".categories_list").prop("checked", is_checked).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }

});   
});
```

Becuase in Normal checkbox, if you give disabled="true" or disabled="false" will give the same output.

Comment: didn't work, they are still all disabled after i deselect 'select all'